# Non-Hausdorff one-point compactifications

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427052) regarding one-space compactifications.

First recall a few definitions.  An *embedding* is a continuous injective map $c:X\to Y$ that gives a homeomorphism from $X$ to its image.  A *[compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(mathematics))* of $X$ is an embedding of $X$ as a dense subset of a compact space $Y$.  By identifying $X$ with its image in $Y$ one just needs to extend $X$ to a bigger set $Y$ and give $Y$ a compact topology such that the subspace topology on $X$ coincides with the original topology on $X$.

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a noncompact topological space.  A compactification $X^*=X\cup\{\infty\}$
obtained by adding a single point will be called a *one-point compactification*.  ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) seems to reserve that term for the case of $X$ locally compact Hausdorff.  In that case there is a unique Hausdorff one-point compactification of $X$.  But I'll use the term more generally for convenience.)

I am interested in finding the range of all possible one-point compactifications of $X$.  So find all the ways to give a compact topology to $X^*$ that induces the original topology on $X$.  The fact that $X$ is dense in $X^*$ follows automatically because $X$ is not compact, so it cannot be closed in a compact space.

**General fact:** It is shown in the linked question at the top that every open nbhd of $\infty$ must be the complement in $X^*$ of a closed compact subset of $X$.

I can think of the following different cases of one-point compactifications:

1. The [**Alexandroff extension**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of $X$ with topology
   $$\tau_1=\tau\cup\{(X\setminus C)\cup\{\infty\}:C\text{ is compact and closed in }X\}\;.$$
   Starting with the topology on $X$, we have added as many open nbhds of $\infty$ as possible.
   The inclusion map of $X$ into $X^*$ is an open embedding.  This is the largest topology on $X^*$ with an open embedding.
2. The [**open extension topology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_topology) given by
   $$\tau_2=\tau\cup\{X^*\}\;.$$
   Starting with the topology on $X$, we have added a single nbhd of $\infty$, namely the whole space.
   The inclusion map is an open embedding.  This is the smallest topology on $X^*$ with an open embedding.
3. Any topology intermediate between $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$.  $X$ will also be open in $X^*$ and the topology will contain all of $\tau$.  For nhbds of $\infty$ one has to pick of suitable subfamily of the complements of all closed compact subsets of $X$.  For example, the complements of all finite closed compact subsets, or the complements of all countable closed compact subsets.

These should cover all cases of one-point compactification with an open embedding.
($X$ is open in $X^*$ if and only if the topology on $X^*$ contains all of $\tau$.)

Now is every one-point compactfication of $X$ always an open embedding?  Are there examples where $X$ is not open in $X^*$?  What are conditions on $X$ that ensure the only one-point compactifications are the ones above?

---

Side note: One is usually not interested in taking a one-point compactification of a space $X$ that is already compact.  But I still find the following observation worth noting.  If $X$ is compact, the Alexandroff extension of $X$ will not be a compactification, since $\infty$ is then an isolated point and hence $X$ is not dense in $X^*$.  But the open extension topology on $X$ plus one point is always a one-point compactification (with $X$ open in $X^*$).

If $X$ is a one-point space, it has exactly two one-point compactifications.  The open extension topology is the [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space).  The other is the two point space with the indiscrete topology, in which case the embedding is not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is not compact, then every one-point compactification of $X$ is an open embedding.  Indeed, suppose $X$ is not open in a one-point compactification $X^*=X\cup\{\infty\}$.  This means there is some $x\in X$ such that every open neighborhood of $x$ in $X^*$ contains $\infty$.  But then every open neighborhood of $x$ contains a neighborhood of $\infty$, and thus its complement is a compact subset of $X$.  Since $X$ is embedded in $X^*$, this means that every open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ has compact complement.  But this implies $X$ is compact, since every open cover of $X$ includes a set which contains $x$, and then the complement of that set is covered by finitely many other sets in the cover.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.