# One point (non-Hausdorff) compactification of compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

A compactification of a space $X$ is an embedding $f:X \to Y$ so that (1) $Y$ is compact, (2) $f(X)$ is dense in $Y$. If furthermore, $Y\setminus f(X)$ is a single point, we say it is a one point compactification.

> If we assume $X$ is a compact and Hausdorff space (thus LCH), does there exist a (non-Hausdorff) $Y$, such that there exists $f:X \to Y$ that is a one-point compactification of $X$?

If we require $Y$ to be Hausdorff, this is impossible see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971130/one-point-compactification-of-a-compact-space). However, since compact does not imply closed in general, I'm not sure the case when we relax this condition. In particular, even if compactification exists, is it unique up to homeomorphism?

$S^{1}$ is an example, but I cannot think of a compactification. (Edit: I think taking $S_1 \sqcup S_1$ and quotient it out by a space so that every two points on the circle are combined besides 1 point might be an example, but I need to think more carefully, it might not work)

Comment: Your example works, but it's not unique. Add a point and give it only one neighborhood: the whole space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the set given by $X$ together with some other point $\infty$. Declare a set to be open if it's either open in $X$ or the whole space. Then the inclusion of $X$ into $Y$ is continuous and the closure of $X$ is all of $Y$ since $\{ \infty \}$ is not open. Moreover, $Y$ is trivially compact, as any open cover includes an open set containing $\infty$ but the only such set is $Y$ itself.

For what it's worth, in my opinion, the moral is that non-$T_1$ spaces are terrible, not anything interesting about compactifications.

Comment: Your example could be made T1: let $\infty$ have cofinite neighborhoods. This again compactifies any T1 space as a dense subset of a T1 compact space.

Comment: @stevenclontz good example, and my editorialization is not great.

Comment: @StevenClontz Thank you for the example. Also, I guess even if we require T1, the one-point compactification is not unique to homeomorphism?

Comment: Correct: this works for any T1 space, including a locally compact T2 space, and usually the result isn't T2, making it different from the standard compactification (unless the base space is discrete).

Comment: @StevenClontz Sorry I don't quite understand. In this case, I require the original space to be compact and T2, so I don't think there is a standard one point compactification?

Comment: Gotcha. I'll add a supplementary answer with the details when I can.

Answer (score 5):

1. No finite space $X$ has a $T_1$ one-point compactification $Y=X\cup\{\infty\}$: since $X$ is finite, $X$ must be closed in $Y$ and therefore cannot be dense.
2. Every infinite $T_1$ space $X$ has a $T_1$ one-point compactification: let $Y=X\cup\{\infty\}$, where neighborhoods of $\infty$ are co-finite.
3. $T_1$ one-point compactifications are not unique. Consider $[0,1]$, and let $\infty\in[0,1]\cup\{\infty\}$ have basic open neighborhoods of the form $(a,1)\cup\{\infty\}$. This is a strictly finer topology than the one described in (2).
4. Similar to (1), no compact space $X$ has a KC (Kompacts are Closed) compactification $Y=X\cup\{\infty\}$: since $X$ is compact, $X$ must be closed in $Y$ and therefore cannot be dense.
5. Every non-compact KC space $X$ has a [$k_2$-Hausdorff (P171)](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000171) one-point compactification: let $Y=X\cup\{\infty\}$, where neighborhoods of $\infty$ are co-compact (the [Alexandrov extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension)). To see this, note $\{\infty\}$ is not open as $X$ is not compact, so $X$ is dense. $k_2$-Hausdorff was shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4761212/86887).
6. $k_2$-Hausdorff one-point compactifications are not unique. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4839830/86887) shows two distinct $k_2$-Hausdorff compactifications for $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 5):

Assume the topological space $(X,\tau)$ is not compact.  All its non-Hausdorff one-point compactifications $Y=X\cup\{\infty\}$ can be described, as show in [Non-Hausdorff one-point compactifications](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3817485/non-hausdorff-one-point-compactifications).

There are basically three types:

1. The [**Alexandroff extension**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of $X$ with topology
   $$\tau_1=\tau\cup\{(X\setminus C)\cup\{\infty\}:C\text{ is compact and closed in }X\}\;.$$
   Starting with the topology on $X$, we have added as many open nbhds of $\infty$ as possible.
   This is the largest topology on $Y$ that satisfies the requirements.
2. The [**open extension topology**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_topology) given by
   $$\tau_2=\tau\cup\{Y\}\;.$$
   Starting with the topology on $X$, we have added a single nbhd of $\infty$, namely the whole space.
   This is the smallest topology on $Y$ that satisfies the requirements.
3. Any topology intermediate between $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$.  $X$ will also be open in $Y$ and the topology will contain all of $\tau$.  For nhbds of $\infty$ one has to pick of suitable subfamily of the complements of all closed compact subsets of $X$.  For example, the complements of all finite closed compact subsets, or the complements of all countable closed compact subsets, and many others.

---

If $X$ is compact, the Alexandroff extension is not a compactification of $X$ because $X$ is not dense in $Y$.  But, as mentioned in the other answers, the open extension topology is always a compactification (with $X$ open in $Y$).

Additional example: suppose $X$ is a singleton.  Then there are exactly two one-point compactifications of $X$.  The open extension topology is the Sierpinski space.  The other one is the two point space with the indiscrete topology (the embedding is not open in this case).